# Comparison of largest eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ lower triangular matrices with diagonal entries $1$ and below diagonal entries as $0$ or $1$. 
Suppose $A$ and $B$ has $a$ , $b$ number of $1$s. Let $a,b\ge 2n-1$.

Is it right that when $a>b$, the largest eigenvalue of $AA^T$ is greater than that of $BB^T$? if so, any hint to prove it?

Comment: Surely you mean that when $a > b$, the largest eigenvalue of $AA^T$ is **greater** than that of $BB^T$, no?

Comment: The assertion $a,b\geqslant n-1$ is trivial. In fact, since the entries of the diagonals of both $A$ and $B$ are all equal to $1$, $a,b\geqslant n$.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos, it was a typo, now I have edited.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, yes you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course no; why would that be? It is a typical *"global vs local"* situation. If the off-diagonal ones of $A$, though more numerous, are spread thin, and those of $B$ are lumped together in one corner, then $B$ might just as well win.

The example below seems to suffice. Sorry I didn't have the time to find one with nice roots.
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0 &0 &0\\
1 &1 &0 &0\\
0 &1 &1 &0\\
1 &0 &1 &1
\end{pmatrix},\quad
B=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0 &0 &0\\
0 &1 &0 &0\\
0 &1 &1 &0\\
0 &1 &1 &1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Can you please direct me to any reference for this **global vs local** explanation?

Comment: There is no reference; this is just my way to understand these things. For a simpler example, say we have $\int_a^bf(x)dx>\int_a^bg(x)dx$ (a _global_ condition); can $g(x)$ be greater than $f(x)$ at some point (_locally_)? Of course it can. Same thing here.